# This is homework. Can someone help me figure out what I have declared wrong? I keep getting an error when I give Double

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

```
Function quadratic (a As double, b As double, c As double) As Double
    Dim x,y As Double   

    if (a = 0) then
        Console.Writeline("no solution for a = 0")      
    else if 
            ((b * b - 4 * a * c) <0)
            Console.Writeline("no real solutions")          
    else
            x = ((- b + Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / ( 2 * a))
            y = ((- b - Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / ( 2 * a))

            if (x > y) then
                Console.Writeline(x)
            else 
                Console.Writeline(y)
            End if 
    End if
End Function
```

Comment: Please state your problem, not just your code. Are you getting an error? Are you getting a wrong result? What is the program trying to do? While some of those questions can be figured out in seconds, some of them take much more effort, or running the compiler and copying your code; doing as much for potential answerers shows respect for their time. Also, tag your question appropriately, with [tag:vb.net], so relevant experts can see your question more easily.

Comment: asking homeworks is a good thing at SO but make sure you post your errors and research you have done to tackle down the errors..

Comment: Guess the homework is going to be late this week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to check your math for you :-) but if you change this:

```
else if 
  ((b * b - 4 * a * c) <0)
  Console.Writeline("no real solutions")
```

To this:

```
ElseIf ((b * b - 4 * a * c) < 0) Then
  Console.Writeline("no real solutions")
```

It compiles and runs...